# Java - classLoader - reading files in a jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a project made in `Intelij` where I have a function which reads some data from a file using :

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(excelFilePath);
```

and it works fine.

Now, I want to make a `jar` with the project + files and call that function from another project. The files are added to the `jar`, but when calling the function i get a null pointer exception, the stream is `null`;

The file path is something like 
`"exel\\filename"` and it's on `res/exel` folder, where `res` is marked as a resource folder.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Open the jar, file may not be jared.

Comment: the file is there, i checked

Comment: Write a main method in jar and try to run it outside intelij. In first case it may be picking somewhere different location.

Comment: @ZeeshanBilal i just did that, and i got the same error.

Comment: Do u did it in your first one right?

Comment: first time i added the jar to a new project and called that function, not i made a main method that calls that function and directly run the jar. same error.

Comment: Create main in same jar where function and file present. It will help.dwbug the probelm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to replace

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(excelFilePath);
```

with

```
InputStream stream =  MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(excelFilePath);
```

and also format the excelFilePath to begin with a '/'.